# Get unique path irrespective of symlinks

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have two paths to the sd memory i get when accessing.

> 1. /mnt/sdcard
> 2. /storage/sdcard0

Actually both point to the same file location but still I am not sure how I could find that both are same and show only one location.

Even doing

> file.getAbsolutePath()

on individual file objects, gives different paths. (I was expecting them to be giving same path as they are pointing to same directory).

Comment: This is completely expected behavior because of how Android handles external storage. Can I ask what the use case is that you need a unique file path to the external directory?

Comment: I want to show all available storage options provided by the device. 
i.e. Internal Storage, External SD etc